# How to split using numpy

Tags: python

I have a dataset with 6 columns and am trying to make an LSTM model. To do so I have to convert it first. While I'm using the code below, I get this error:

> `"ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 6"`

How this can be resolved?

My data looks like this:

```
Time    Pres    OQ  WQ  WT  Flag
0       5000    0   0   0   1
0.1     5000    0   0   0   1
0.2     5000    0   0   0   1
0.3     5000    0   0   0   1
0.4     5000    0   0   0   1
```

and here is my code:

```py
f = open(fname)
data = f.read()
f.close()
lines = data.split('\n')
header = lines[0].split(',')
lines = lines[1:]
print(header)
print(len(header))
print(len(lines))


import numpy as np
float_data = np.zeros((len(lines), len(header)))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')[1:]]
    float_data[i, :] = values
```

Comment: Without the model, it is a bit hard to understand the question. Maybe you can also include the input shape and how to replicate the error.

Comment: it's just the beginning part of my code, and the error arises for this part. My data shape is (3500, 6) and want to create the same output shape. But, somehow the float-data part creates 5 columns...

Comment: In the for loop add a `print(values)` to see which column is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are omitting the Time column when you do this: `values = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')[1:]]`. Don't slice the list and it will work

Comment: The problem was related to "lines = data.split('\n')". To fix the issue, this line should be replaced by:
`lines = data.splitlines()`